# Visio UML Sequence Diagram - How do I remove Top Package from Actor?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010, uml

Hi guys I'm currently building a sequence diagram on Visio 2010. When I add an actor it has the name Top Package:: by default - which I cannot remove (I have tried deleting from properties).

Does anyone know how to remove it or a way to get by?

Thank you

[image: Visio UML sequence diagram]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I know of is
select the shape -> right-click -> Shape Display Options -> abd turn off Name
but that removes all the text.

Answer (score 0):

In the "Shape Display Options", section "Suppress" check "Package qualifier name" and "Top Package::" disappears.